# Spring Boot JPA : GetRequest gives me no output

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

**Hi guys,
My GetRequest gives me a 500, and I don't know why.
I am trying to make a JPQL Query to select Artist name  and get the names of them with the getArtistbySomething
The SQL Select statement is working in MySQL**

#My Repository:

```
public interface ArtistRepository extends JpaRepository<Artist, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT a.name, a.id, count(p.artist) FROM Artist a, Production p, Clip c WHERE p.artist = a.id AND p.clip = c.id AND c.size > 5000 and p.date > ?1 GROUP BY p.artist order by count(p.artist) desc ")
    public List<Artist> getArtistBySomething(long date);

}
```

## My Restcontroller with the getRequest:

```
import ch.zhaw.springboot.entities.Artist;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.repositories.ArtistRepository;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.repositories.ClipRepository;
import ch.zhaw.springboot.repositories.ProductionRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class ArtistRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ArtistRepository artistRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ClipRepository clipRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductionRepository productionRepository;


    @GetMapping(value = "universal2/artist")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Artist>> getArtist() {
        List<Artist> result = this.artistRepository.findAll();

        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Artist>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Artist>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }


    
   @GetMapping(value = "universal2/artist/{date}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Artist>> getArtistBySomething(@PathVariable("date") long date) {
        List<Artist> result = this.artistRepository.getArtistBySomething(date);

        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Artist>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Artist>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }}
```

## The getArtistBySomething Output in JSON with URL: http://localhost:8080/universal2/artist/1516233600

```
"timestamp": "2021-01-07T11:57:46.250+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/universal2/artist/100': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity ch.zhaw.springboot.restcontroller.ArtistRestController.getArtistById(long), public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity ch.zhaw.springboot.restcontroller.ArtistRestController.getArtistBySomething(long)}",
"path": "/universal2/artist/1516233600"
```

}

I would be very grateful for any advice!

Kind regards!

Comment: please share the exception description and stack trace, someone will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mapped `getArtist()` and `getArtistBySomething(@PathVariable("date") long date)`  to the same endpoint `universal2/artist`. To fix it you can add something like this the second one `@GetMapping(value = "universal2/artist/date/{date}")`

Answer (score 0):

Change your getArtistBySomething() method argument to RequestParams instead of Path variable

Comment: I get the same Error

Answer (score 0):

Please find my solution that will suite your requirement with same configuration.
the only change I have done is this line:
@RequestMapping("/portal")

This is the second output printed in console:
Path Variable value: 546546456 (I passed this value in getArtistBySomething)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/portal")
public class TestControllers {

    @Autowired
    CronjobServe cronjobServe;
    @Autowired
    ReportService reportService;

    @GetMapping(value = "universal2/artist")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Languages>> getArtist() {
        List<Languages> result = reportService.getAllLanguages();
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Languages>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Languages>>(result, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "universal2/artist/{date}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Languages>> getArtistBySomething(@PathVariable("date") long date) {
        System.out.println("Path Variable value: " + date);
        List<Languages> result = reportService.getAllLanguages();

        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Languages>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Languages>>(result, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your **GET** mapping is path is same so spring-boot is not able to identify the path value n because of that it is throwing massage like **"message": "Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/universal2/artist/100'**

To overcome the the above problem, you can  make  path variable optional like below:--

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/universal2")
    public class ArtistRestController {
    
        @Autowired
        private ArtistRepository artistRepository;
        @Autowired
        private ClipRepository clipRepository;
        @Autowired
        private ProductionRepository productionRepository;
    
    
        @GetMapping(value = {"/artist","/artist/{date}"})
        public ResponseEntity<List<Artist>> getArtistDeatails(@PathVariable(required = false) long date) {
        
   
        if(date!=null) 
    {
         List<Artist> result = this.artistRepository.getArtistBySomething(date);

    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Artist>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
         } 
       else {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Artist>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
      } 
   else
     {
       List<Artist> result = this.artistRepository.findAll();

        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Artist>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Artist>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
      }
        
 }
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.